# having trouble running a flutter them on adroid studio

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to the intricate dev world. Im a novice at best and am use to working with WordPress. is there anyway the community could give me a few bullet points on how to upload a flutter them from envato to android studios and then to the emulator, Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with Flutter from the official documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install). This guide provide information about how to install Flutter SDK on your computer, how to build and run simple application on the emulator or a real device. Guide also provide information about integration with supported IDE and text editors (Android Studio, VS Code etc.) and describes next steps to learn Flutter.